# Merge Dictionaries oin a list with the same key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a `list` of `dicts`, like this:

```
x = [{'a': 3}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}]
```

and I would like to have a something like this

```
x = [{'a': 4}, {'b': 2}, {None: 0}]
```

What is the most memory-friendly way to reach that?

Comment: Not sure what you need this for, but if you need an object that quickly tallies up groups of things, you should check out `collections.Counter`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say:

```
l = [{'a': 3}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}]
```

Now we will extract and add up:

```
res = []
for k in l:
    for i in k:
        s = {i:sum(j[i] for j in l if i in j)}
        if s not in res:
            res.append(s)
```

gives:

```
[{'a': 4}, {'b': 2}, {None: 0}]
```

Or we could use (adapted from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sum-list-of-dictionaries-with-same-key/) ):

```
result = {}
for d in l:
    for k in d.keys():
        result[k] = result.get(k, 0) + d[k]
res = [{i:result[i]} for i in result]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which will naturally update the counts:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [{'a': 3}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}]

counts = Counter()
for d in l:
    counts.update(d)

print([{k: v} for k, v in counts.items()])
```

From the docs for [`collections.Counter.update`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update):

> Elements are counted from an iterable or added-in from another mapping (or counter). Like [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) but adds counts instead of replacing them. Also, the iterable is expected to be a sequence of elements, not a sequence of (key, value) pairs.

You can also use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do the counting:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [{'a': 3}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}]

counts = defaultdict(int)
for d in l:
    for k, v in d.items():
        counts[k] += v

print([{k: v} for k, v in counts.items()])
```

Or you could also count with initializing `0` yourself:

```
l = [{'a': 3}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}]

counts = {}
for d in l:
    for k, v in d.items():
        counts[k] = counts.get(k, 0) + 1

print([{k: v} for k, v in counts.items()])
```

From the docs for [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError).

**Output:**

```
[{'a': 4}, {'b': 2}, {None: 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the one-line code using pandas.

```
L = [{'a': 3}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 1}, {None: 0}]
output = pd.DataFrame(L).sum(axis = 0).to_dict()
```

Comment: one-liners are out-rated :)